# CRUD using Hibernate but without any entities

Tags: hibernate, dynamic, jdbc, entity

Is is possible to do this? I know Hibernate is an ORM tool which maps objects to tables in the database. So we need to have the entities to do CRUD on the corresponding tables.

But in our application entities will be dynamic i.e. Admin User can create person , location forms dynamically and then the tables will also be generated dynamically in the database.

Can we do this using hibernate or we will have to use simple JDBC for this? We dont want to use JDBC as we want our application to run on different databases like Mysql, mssql and oracle.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hibernate without entities is possible. See here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible and I can't even imagine how should this work. To be honest, the whole design of your application seems suspicious, but never mind.

Hibernate is about objects - if you don't know the table structure beforehand, you can't create objects mapping to those tables and you can't use them. You can use maps (`column` -> `value`) instead, but this approach is not supported by Hibernate.

So you do have to fall back to JDBC (but crying out loud, use abstractions like [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) or [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)) since Hibernate does not support such approach.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the reply. I also thought same. Will have to use JDBC I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases are not well adapted for this use case.  You may be better off 
with some key-value store / nosql soltuion